# Wireshark не ловит http пакеты локального сервера

Tags: wireshark

Проблема в том что `Wireshark` не хочет ловить `http` пакеты локального сервера который стоит на `apache (denwer)`. Все остальное ловит без проблем. А локальный сервер игнорирует. С чем это может быть связанно?

Comment: Wireshark, видимо, слушает не локальный сетевой интерфейс?

Comment: @andreymal да нет вроде бы. Не слушает.

Comment: Как-то непонятно вы ответили, так какой интерфейс он слушает?

Comment: @andreymal слушает сетевой интерфейс. Fiddler ловит эти запросы, хром тоже ловит, wireshark не ловит.

Comment: Какой сетевой интерфейс? В любой системе их как минимум два

Comment: @andreymal ethernet

Comment: Ну вот и ответ на ваш вопрос, локальный трафик никогда не будет проходить через ethernet, на то он и локальный

Comment: Правда, я к сожалению не помню, как в винде называется локалхост

Comment: @andreymal а как тогда ловить локальный трафик?

Comment: Выбрать локальный сетевой интерфейс, ваш кэп. На линуксе это lo0, на винде не помню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, разговор идет о Windows, по скольку на линуксе такой проблемы нет.

Дело в том, что когда трафик прередается внутри одной машины то используется виртуальный сетевой адаптер (loopback). Wireshark поддерживает перехват трафика на loopback интерфейсах на линуксах, макосах но не на винде, в силу особенностей реализации виртульного интерфейса на виндах.

Если очень нужно слушать локальный трафик, и Fiddler не устраивает, то могу посоветовать использовать утилитку [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap), которая записывает трафик в файл, который потом можно просмотреть в Wireshark.